# build docker with postgres and java

Tags: docker, centos

I want to extend docker ([postgresql-96-centos7](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/postgresql-96-centos7/)) to add java. 
I try to build next dockerfile:

```
FROM centos/postgresql-96-centos7

RUN yum update -y && \
yum install -y wget && \
yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk && \
yum clean all

# Set environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /root

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

with command:

```
docker image build -t centos_pgs_java .
```

But there is an error:

```
Step 3/6 : RUN yum update -y && yum install -y wget && yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk && yum clean all
 ---> Running in d93a94a61a11
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/rpm/Group'
You need to be root to perform this command.
The command '/bin/sh -c yum update -y && yum install -y wget && yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk && yum clean all' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How to rewrite RUN command in dockerfile with root access?

Comment: ...why do you need a JVM in a database container?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) documentation:

> The USER instruction sets the user name (or UID) and optionally the
>   user group (or GID) to use when running the image and for any RUN, CMD
>   and ENTRYPOINT instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile.

So, you need to change user to `root`, execute RUN layer and return user to `26` as it defined in `centos/postgresql-96-centos7` docker image.

The final `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM centos/postgresql-96-centos7

USER root

RUN yum update -y && \
yum install -y wget && \
yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk && \
yum clean all

USER 26

# Set environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /root

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Image build succesfully but there is a warning:

Comment: What is the warning you got? It seems it is hidden by some formatting issues.